# Internet very slow on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I am unsure what has happened, but the internet on my ubuntu machine is 1-2 megs max.

This is the output of `speedtest-cli`

```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 0.90 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed...........^T...........................................................................................
Upload: 2.42 Mbit/s
```

I have tried disabling ipv6

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up changing the dns in the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` to

```
    nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.2.2.2
```

Since I had the first one as `1.1.1.1`.  and that was causing issues